# Installing Gulp on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I ran the instructions on the main gulp page and gulp does not run:

```
        ole@mki$ npm install gulp-cli -g
        /home/ole/.npm-global/bin/gulp -> /home/ole/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js
        + gulp-cli@2.0.1
        updated 1 package in 6.883s
        ole@mki:$ npm install gulp -D
        npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
        npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

        + gulp@3.9.1
        updated 1 package in 10.576s
        ole@mki:$ gulp --help
        The program 'gulp' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
        sudo apt install gulp
```

Comment: `npm install gulp -g`

Comment: Tried it - same result.

Comment: What does `node --version` give you? `npm run` is for npm scripts, not for running Javascript code. To do that, use `node`: `node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js`

Comment: node --version is 9.5.0.  Aha!  Thanks for refreshing that concept for me.  I can run gulp from `node_modules/.bin/gulp` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [NPM Without Sudo Instructions](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) I had a mistake in `~/.npmrc`.  Instead of `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages` I had `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-global`.

Answer (score 1):

What’s the error message?
Or try instead of `Sudo apt install glup`
Try

```
Sudo apt-get install glub
```

Comment: That will install a version managed by the ubuntu repositories.  They tend to be out of date, so I prefer to stick to the npm versions, as I know the gulp maintainers update these.

Comment: Try and find the website and find the newest version and install it via ‘wget‘